# Random NullPointerException in Compiler.loadFile with no cause

Tags: clojure, nullpointerexception

I have some code that ran for hours and then spontaneously threw a NPE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(/tmp/form-init1523641998694521475.clj:1:73)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7391)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7317)
        at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:275)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:277)
        at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:308)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:342)
        at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:339)
        at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:421)
        at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:384)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:383)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
        at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

By the time this happened, the program had done all of the things it usually does, so I don't know why it spontaneously called `load-script`, which file it was reading, and why it failed.

There is no more context. I don't have any information on how to reproduce this, except to try again and run for a few hours.

Any ideas about how I can diagnose this?

Comment: Matching those line numbers up with the source, it looks like you're running a pre-1.9 version of Clojure. Maybe 1.8? Earlier? It looks like those code paths have changed quite a bit since then.

Comment: How are you running the program? I think the issue is outside your code.

Comment: Clojure version 1.8.0 @JonahBenton. I found the problem, it was my own NPE but the stack dump was being removed. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an NPE in my own code, but the JVM had decided to omit the stacktrace. This was fixed by using the `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` JVM flag. [This article provided the explanation](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-05-11-clojure-no-stacktrace.html).